# Gitlab runner : bash: line 526: /build/build.sh: No such file or director

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab

I installed Gitlab on my own server and I'm trying to configure Gitlab runner to check code quality, etc.

I'm getting an error I don't understand :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.8.0 (4745a6f3)
on mydomain.fr Q7uHJf81
Using Shell executor...
Running on mydomain.fr...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/Q7uHJf81/0/root/myrepository'...
Checking out c6e2f2f0 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ # Auto DevOps variables and functions # collapsed multi-line command
$ /build/build.sh
bash: line 526: /build/build.sh: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

What is this build.sh file and where can I find it ?

Thanks !

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this same issue after setting up the gitlab-runner and registering it with a shell executor.  The error went away after **adding in a .gitlab-ci.yml** file to the root of my repository.

If you can share your .gitlab-ci.yml, it might be possible to provide more specific help.